# How do I return a function from another function and then call it?

Tags: javascript, closures

Can someone explain why the code below fails?
How i can access the `zip` function using closures? I want it to get it to print out `value1`.

```
function foo() {
    var bar;

    function zip() {
        var quux = 'value1';
        bar = true;    
        console.log(quux);
    }

    quux = 'value2';
    console.log(quux);
    return zip;      
}

foo();

var a = zip;

a();
```

It is currently saying `zip is not defined`.

Comment: Because `zip` is undefined outside `foo()`. You have to use `var a = foo()` instead.

Comment: Hmm it's interesting what are you trying there. You might wanna take a look at [the revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
foo()()
```

or the same with assignment to a variable:

```
var a = foo();
a();
```

Note that it will output both `value2` and then `value1.`

### How is this working?

In order to make it easier to understand the provided code, consider the following example which makes the same result as your code:

```
function foo() {
  var bar;
  quux = 'value2';
  console.log(quux);

  return function() {
    var quux = 'value1';
    bar = true;

    console.log(quux);
  };
}

var a = foo(); // executes code, returns function and stores it in a variable
a(); // executes function, stored in a variable
```

I guess, it is easier to understand this code now - it executes some code, returns a function, which you call later.

Now, consider another example:

```
function foo() {
  var bar;
  quux = 'value2';
  console.log(quux);

  var zip = function() {
    var quux = 'value1';
    bar = true;

    console.log(quux);
  };

  return zip;
}

var a = foo(); // executes code, returns function and stores it in a variable
a(); // executes function, stored in a variable
```

This code does the same, but it stores a function in a variable before returning as result. The code that you have provided in example almost does not differ from the last example, except for function declaration:

These are almost equivalent ([why almost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)):

```
var zip = function() {
};

function zip() {
}
```

Comment: but is this using a closure? and how can i get it to run zip();

Comment: @user5519770 Yes, `var a = foo()` will output `value1` and return a `zip` function as a variable. Then, you call `a` function using `a()` and output `value2`.

Comment: ok i have accepted the answer cheers. but how the heck is that working?!

Comment: @user5519770 Oh, that's all about JS and closures. Maybe, this example will help you. The code that you have provided is almost the same as  http://jsfiddle.net/9bzdbcdg/1/. Is it easier to understand how this one is working?

Answer (score 0):

The function 'foo' is returning the 'zip' function but not called(ex: zip()). Hence you may have to capture the returning function in a variable.

```
var f = foo();
```

Then call:

```
f();
```

Output:

```
value2
value1
```